# Sampling from a data table in R

Tags: r, random, datatable

I'm new to R and I would like to know how to take a certain number of samples from a csv file made entirely of numbers in Excel. I managed to import the data to R and use each number as a row and then take random rows as samples but it seems impractical. The whole file is displayed as a column and I took some samples with the next code:

```
Heights[sample(nrow(Heights), 5), ]
[1] 1.84 1.65 1.73 1.70 1.72
```

Also please let me know if there is a way to repeat this step at least 100 times and save each sample in another chart maybe, to work with it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you'd take 100 samples and store them:

```
my_samples <- replicate(100, Heights[sample(nrow(Heights), 5), ])
```

If your .csv file just comma separated values of one type (the heights), and not structured as a table, you may want to turn it into a vector instead. Most R functions that read textual formats of data are going to turn the data into a data frame or some other table like format.

```
heights <- unlist(strsplit(readLines("yourfile.csv"), ","))
```

`readLines("yourfile.csv")` with a .csv file of comma separated values will turn it into a character vector. `strsplit()` then does the separating work for you.

To put this all together, with a dummy example:

```
writeLines(c("1,2,3,4,5", "6,7,8,9,10"), "test.csv")
heights <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(readLines("test.csv"), ",")))
set.seed(123)
my_samples <- replicate(100, sample(heights, 5))
dim(my_samples)
# [1]    5 100
```

You can see that my_samples is a matrix of 5 rows (with each row corresponding to a single element sampled from `heights`), and 100 columns (with each column corresponding to one of one hundred sampling events).

Comment: Thank you very much. That did it. Just one more question, how do I call a sample from my_samples? Would it be something like my_samples[1], like in other languages?

Comment: Because it's structured as a matrix (you could do it differently), if you want one of the 100 columns, you use the form `my_matrix[row, column]`, or here, for the 40th sample, `my_samples[ , 40]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the infer package that is used for bootstrapping.

```
library(infer)
rep_sample_n(size = 100, replace = TRUE, reps = 1)
```

Here "size" is the number of samples. "replace" (if true) allows you to replace an observation when sampling  - that is, you spin the roulette wheel without taking numbers off the wheel once they come up. 'reps' allows you to repeat the sampling process.